# Iterating over JSON

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I know immediately this is going to be such a simple answer, but my issue here has been when I'm searching for help I can't quite get the search I'm looking for.

So I understand basics of how to iterate over a JSON array. But I want something like the code below to work where what follows 'finaldataset[i]' is a variable rather than a key in the JSON.

```
function iterateOverJSON(s){
for(var i = 0; i<finaldataset.length; i++){
 console.log(finaldataset[i].s)
}
    }
```

Say finaldataset is an array of movies and attributes about each movie I want to be able to pass the function a value, say "director" or "movieLength", anyway you get the point. Many thanks for any help

Comment: Use brackets for dynamic key extraction: finaldataset[i][s]

Comment: BTW: There is no such thing as a `JSON` array.  There is `JSON`, which is a string, and when one parses JSON they get a mix of objects, arrays, and primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use brackets

```
function iterateOverJSON(s){
  for(var i = 0; i<finaldataset.length; i++){
   console.log(finaldataset[i][s])
  }
}
```

Comment: BAH! of course. I thought 'finaldataset[i].[s]' before but it didnt work. Didn't realise I was so close! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  For example:

```
function iterateOverJSON(prop) {
    return finaldataset.map(function(x) { return x[prop]; });
}

// example usage
var directors = iterateOverJSON('director');
var movieLength = iterateOverJSON('movieLength');
```